# What would be a good harmonic progression for this example?

Tags: theory, chord-progressions, counterpoint

For my advanced theory seminar class this semester, I am being introduced to formal counterpoint writing procedures. For a homework assignment this week, I have to write a good bass line (First Species) to go against this given melody line. The first step is I am supposed to determine the "implied harmonic progression."

We're in C major here. I hear the first group of eighth notes as a I chord and the next group as a IV chord. Is it normal for IV to go to the vi chord? That is not one of the common progressions I was taught.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: IV-vi and ii-vi are commonplace enough (at least compared to iii) in my experience.

Comment: (It's years since I did this stuff.YEARS!) Yes, C and F in the first bar, I think. Then you could try | G#F#G# A  B C B D | C Bb A G etc, Maybe? The first half bar should be springy, to contrast with the step-wise stuff. Like C(low one) G E C(high one)

Comment: What about this bass line?  c e | f f# | g g, | c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hear it as:

C  F | Am Dm | C/E G7 | C

I IV | vi ii | I6  V7 | I

But there are other possible interpretations as well.